# Increase the width and height of the image extracted

Tags: excel, vba

I am extracting a excel table as png file the extraction is ok, but the extracted file is too zoomed out and when i zoom in it is all blurr, i am going to attach the image in a mail so the data should be clear visible,Any idea where to change the code ,changed the width and height below to almost 50 no change

```
With ChTemp.Parent
   .Width = PicTemp.Width + 8
   .Height = PicTemp.Height + 8
```

Here is the code

```
Sub check(filename As String, picturename As String)

Dim myWb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i, j As Long, LastRow As Integer
'Dim filename As String, picturename As String

Set myWb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=filename)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate


Dim FName As String
FName = picturename
Dim pic_rng As Range
Dim ShTemp As Worksheet
Dim ChTemp As Chart
Dim PicTemp As Picture
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set pic_rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:N42")
Set ShTemp = Worksheets.Add
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShTemp.Name
Set ChTemp = ActiveChart
pic_rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
ChTemp.Paste
Set PicTemp = Selection
With ChTemp.Parent
   .Width = PicTemp.Width + 8
   .Height = PicTemp.Height + 8
End With
ChTemp.Export filename:=picturename, FilterName:="jpg"
'UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(FName)
Kill FName
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ShTemp.Delete

myWb.Close False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection in your case is the Chart itself, and nothing will be increase n its dimensions. And the code must paste the picture **in the increased chart**... Otherwise, any increase does not help.

Try the next way, please:

```
'what you have in your code...
'.....
pic_rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
With ChTemp.Parent
   .Width = rng.Width + 10
   .Height = rng.Height + 10
End With
ChTemp.Paste
ChTemp.Export filename:=picturename, FilterName:="jpg"
'your code...
'...
```